# Encoding with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with dataset Titanic. I want to separate numerical columns from category columns.
I try to do this whit this lines of codes:

```
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype


print("Numeric columns")
for column in dataset.columns:
    if is_numeric_dtype(dataset[column]):
        print(column)
print("----------------------------------")        
print("Category columns")        
for column in dataset.columns:
    if is_string_dtype(dataset[column]):
        print(column)
```

So now I see clearly what is numerical and what is categorical columns.

```
Numeric columns
PassengerId
Survived
Pclass
Age
SibSp
Parch
Fare
----------------------------------
Category columns
Name
Sex
Ticket
Cabin
Embarked
```

Next step is to convert all categorical columns with label encoding. I try to do this on this way:

```
columns_names = dataset.columns.tolist()

new_column = dataset[columns_names].astype('category')
new_column = new_column.cat.codes
print(new_column)
```

But obviously I made some mistake and code don't work properly. So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and making label encoding for each categorical columns ?

Comment: There is already an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67135882/11989081 which explains how you can apply the label encoder to different data frame columns.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I am looking something with Pandas while this example is with different package.

Comment: aren't you typecasting all column to category type here -  columns_names = dataset.columns.tolist()
new_column = dataset[columns_names].astype('category')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert your data to the respective codes, the initial relation is lost, so there is no way to go from the codes back to the categories:

```
new_column = dataset[columns_names].astype('category')
new_columns = new_columns.transform(lambda s: s.cat.codes)
```

Using [`LabelEncoders`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) is, indeed a better way to address this.